# Binary image classification with XGboost as classifier instead of neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, transfer-learning

I am looking for resources that can guide me to use XGboost as my final classifier after feature extraction by CNN and how to save the features generated by CNN and use it for classification by any other techniques like random forest or xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

For classifying the images based on the custom classifier please find the following link

https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03541

In this for feature extraction is done by CNN and classification is based upon SVM